# Remove Duplicate rows but Keeping the highest value

Tags: excel, vba

I have 8 `Columns` with Data and there are multiple duplicates in `Column 1` and other columns have values and texts.

I want to keep the `Column 5` highest values and remove duplicates from `Column 1`.

Your help will be appreciated.

```
Sub KeepHighvalue()

Dim MyRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Sht1 As worksheet
Set Sht1 = Worksheets("Sheet1") 
LastRow = Sht1 .Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Set MyRange = Sht1 .Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
MyRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes

End Sub
```

usaupload.com/5g09/Data.xlsx

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with pivot Tables? Also, if you have Excel365 you could add to your code MAXIFS, loop trough your column A and if the value in column 5 matchs the highest do nothing, else delete row.

Comment: Do you like excepting the highest value, for all its occurrences?

Comment: Yes i have tried with Pivot tables and i have more then 2000 plus rows which unique values are nearly 500+. But Picot table is repeating the duplicate. and i am using office 2016.

Comment: Yes i just want the Column 5 rows with highest values where Column A duplicate will be removed.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean, sorry. Your code replaces in A:A column. I think it would be good to edit your question and place o picture with the initial situation and another one with what you need.

Comment: I need to remove duplicate rows in column A, but I want to keep only the unique with the highest value in column E. As I have information in columns B,C,D,F.... but maintain the entire row for those keeped @FaneDuru

Comment: Maybe I am tired, but I still cannot exactly understand what you mean... When you talk about "unique with the highest value` this means that there may be more occurrences of this highest value. In such a case, which row to be kept. The first occurrence? Why don't you try following my suggestion and place two pictures as I suggested (initial and after)?

Comment: I have updated and here is the attached Excel file https://usaupload.com/5g09/Data.xlsx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming it's ok to sort the data (and assuming I've correctly interpreted what you mean by keeping the highest values), the following is one way to approach the problem. It will remove rows (in the defined 8 columns of data, starting at A1), where data is duplicated in column A, keeping rows with the highest value in column E (5).

```
Sub KeepHighvalue()

    Dim lgLastRow&, rgData As Range
    
''' Set target data area (rgData)
    With Worksheets("Sheet1")
        lgLastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rgData = .Range("A1:H" & lgLastRow)
    End With

''' Remove rows with duplicates in column 1, keeping rows with highest values in column 5
    With rgData
        .Sort Key1:=.Columns(5), Order1:=xlDescending, Header:=xlYes
        .RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlYes
    End With

End Sub
```

If sorting isn't ok, the solution is a little more complex.
============================================================
EDIT: Sample Before and After
============================================================
[image]

Comment: Did you test it Spinner? As I read it, if the duplicates are on the same row as the highest value in column 5, the highest value ends up getting deleted.

Comment: Your way of putting the problem is interesting... But it will work only if you determine **where the last occurrence of the highest value in the sorted range is** and adapt `rgData` (used to remove duplicates) to start from the next row. Using `Header:=xlNo`. Otherwise, I cannot understand how only sorting will avoid those rows (max in E:E) deletion, if they will be on the duplicate values rows in A:A...

Comment: Thank you @Spinner but keeps similar higher values.

Comment: @ShRa: Ok. Then my 'best guess' as to what you actually mean is amiss.  Did say "assuming I've correctly interpreted what you mean by keeping the highest values".  The code above removes all duplicates, keeping any single highest value (in column 5) that exists amongst such duplicates.  If that isn't the goal, you need explain the goal better. :)

Comment: @dra_red: Yes I did test, and yes it works. And no, doesn't do as you suggest.
@ FaneDura: Huh?

Comment: I am afraid that **it looks working** only because it happened that in your testing file these specific rows do not have duplicates in the first column. Otherwise, it is difficult to understand how... :) When you want tagging somebody, do not let a space between @ and the user name. It only happened I still have this page open...

Comment: @ShRa: To aid you in explaining, have added an example table Before and After the code above was run. Using that example, can you tell me what outcome you desire if not the outcome shown. Alternately, run it on your own table and post that showing what is wrong.

Comment: @FaneDuru: Yeah. So we'll agree to disagree, and I'll wait for ShRa's response.

Comment: @Spinner, I think your solution is what is being asked for. There might be a miscount considering the original column count was eight while in the data shown has seven? 

My question above was aimed at the potential issue of multiple occurrences of the highest value in column 5. Considering there was potentially other data in the other columns, I would want to leave all instances of the highest value. Your code, as you note above, only keeps a single record of the highest value. Now some data is there, I think your answer is probably what is desired.

Comment: @dra_red: Yeah, I agree. I did see the inconsistency in 8 versus 7 columns. But decided 'meh, I'm sure ShRa knows which is correct, and can adapt as appropriate'. Also considered 'what about duplicates in both A and E?'. But since that wasn't in the specs, figured 'let's get to first base and see if what emerges'. :)

Comment: Yes it is working fine but when there are duplicates appear in the value columns it keep them remains. Please use this link to run the code on given file it has duplicate values in both columns. https://usaupload.com/5g09/Data.xlsx

Comment: Not sure if that means it does all you want, or if there's still an issue you want to address. As you haven't marked this as the answer, I assume it's the latter? If so, you can you state what it does that you don't want or what it doesn't do that you do want?